# display Count of multiple keys in single mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have got a mongo collection which have following type of data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55d5b739f067897648000007"), "did" : "deviceA","key" : "key1"}
```

I need to get count of each key appeared for a device. I have written following aggregate query:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([{'$group':{'_id':{'deviceid':"$did",'keyis':"$key"},'count':{'$sum':1}}}])
```

I get following result:

```
{ "_id" : { "deviceid" : "deviceA", "keyis" : "key1" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "deviceid" : "deviceA", "keyis" : "key2" }, "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "deviceid" : "deviceB", "keyis" : "key1" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "deviceid" : "deviceB", "keyis" : "key3" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "deviceid" : "deviceB", "keyis" : "key4" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "deviceid" : "deviceC", "keyis" : "key2" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "deviceid" : "deviceC", "keyis" : "key3" }, "count" : 2 }
```

What is want is something like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "deviceid" : "deviceA"}, "count_key1" : 1, "count_key2": 3, "count_key3": 0, "count_key4": 0 }
{ "_id" : { "deviceid" : "deviceB"}, "count_key1" : 1, "count_key2": 0, "count_key3": 1, "count_key4": 1 }
{ "_id" : { "deviceid" : "deviceC"}, "count_key1" : 0, "count_key2": 1, "count_key3": 2, "count_key4": 0 }
```

Is it possible to do in single mongo query??

Any help appreciated.

Comment: take a look at [**`$ifNulll`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)

Comment: is your data contains only keys from `key1 to key4` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it .But we can have a work around for this.

I have created a small subset of data like yours (Sorry for bad formatting):

```
 > db.q.find()
   { "_id" : ObjectId("55d5b739f067897648000007"), "did" : "deviceA", "key" : "key1" }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("55d5b739f067897648000008"), "did" : "deviceB", "key" : "key1" }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("55d5b739f067897648000009"), "did" : "deviceB", "key" : "key2" }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("55d5b739f067897648000019"), "did" : "deviceA", "key" : "key2" }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("55d5b739f067897648000201"), "did" : "deviceA", "key" : "key2" }
```

Below query will give the result you wanted :

```
db.q.aggregate([{
'$group':{'_id':{'deviceid':"$did",'keyis':"$key"},
'count':{'$sum':1}}},{'$group':{'_id':{'deviceid':'$_id.deviceid'},
'counts':{'$push':{'name':'$_id.keyis','count':'$count'}}}},
{'$unwind':'$counts'},{
"$project" : {
    "countKey1" : {
        "$cond" : [
            {
                "$eq" : [
                    "key1",
                    "$counts.name"
                ]
            },
            "$counts.count",
            0
        ]
    },"countKey2" : {
        "$cond" : [
            {
                "$eq" : [
                    "key2",
                    "$counts.name"
                ]
            },
            "$counts.count",
            0
        ]
    }}},{
"$group" : {
    "_id" : "$_id",
    "countKey1" : {
        "$max" : "$countKey1"
    },
    "countKey2" : {
        "$max" : "$countKey2"
    }
}
}])
```

//Result :

```
{ "_id" : { "deviceid" : "deviceA" }, "countKey1" : 1, "countKey2" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "deviceid" : "deviceB" }, "countKey1" : 1, "countKey2" : 1 }
```

Here I'm assumed you have limited set of keys and values are known at time of writing query.

For more details on this : [Blog post on dynamic field names by Asya](http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/using-aggregation-framework-to-reshape-schema)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `$sum` with [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) in aggregation as :

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "deviceid": "$did"
    },
    "count_key1": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": ["$key", "key1"]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "count_key2": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": ["$key", "key2"]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "count_key3": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": ["$key", "key3"]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "count_key4": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": ["$key", "key4"]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```